# How to reference the current module in Typescript

Tags: typescript, module

If I import an external module I can reference items in that module via the module variable from the import.

```js
import * as foo from 'foo';

foo.fn()
foo['fn']()
```

But how do I get a reference to the current module context if I want to do something similar?

```js
const thisModule = ???;

thisModule[`fn`]();
```

Comment: im sorry but im confused by what you are wanting.. if the function you wanting to call is in the module you are calling it from you can just call the function

Comment: This isn't exactly my use case, it is just a simplification to share what I want to accomplish.  I actually need to call a function (or instantiate a class) using a string.  Something that is easy when everything is global because I can use global use something like new global['classname']().  But with modules, the classes aren't on global so I want to find the class with something like localmodule['classname'].

Comment: I found a module is able to import itself and then I can use the alias for the module exactly as I hoped to with my question.  It surprised me that this worked because I thought it might be a circular reference.

Comment: Well, it is a circular reference, and you may face problems with static data initialization for example in case you have circular references, actually. But it's not a text inclusion so it's possible

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a dumb thing to do, but you can import the file info itself:

File: `foo.ts`

```
export function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}

import * as self from './foo';

self.foo();
```

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that and was surprised it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Exploring this further I tried something that I didn't think would work, but it did!  The following solution includes a self-referential import which gives me a variable reference to the module.

In filename foo.ts

```js
import * as local from './foo';

export function fn() {
    console.log('fn()');
}

export class bar {
    constructor() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}

local['fn']();
new local['bar']();

// if using a variable
const c = 'bar';
new (<any>local>)[c]();
```

If anyone knows of a more canonical way of accomplishing this I would appreciate the feedback.